DeleteItem API throws error - The provided key element does not match the schema (DynamoDB)
I'm using the java v2 sdk and trying to delete an item from the table using below code
public static DeleteItemResponse deleteDynamoDBItem(String key, String keyVal) {

    Map<String, AttributeValue> keyToGet =
            new HashMap<>();

    keyToGet.put(key, AttributeValue.builder()
            .s(keyVal)
            .build());

    DeleteItemRequest deleteReq = DeleteItemRequest.builder()
            .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .key(keyToGet)
            .build();

    try {
        return DYNAMO_DB.deleteItem(deleteReq);
    } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}

Error is thrown in the logs
"The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: VCTLMOSSUBMSHMCNOMN589ETPJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
DeleteItemResponse response = DataService.deleteDynamoDBItem("userid", "abc");

Below is the table structure


I'm referring below url for example
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/DeleteItem.java

The thing to understand here is that to identify an item uniquely, for example to delete it or update it, you have to supply the primary key. The primary key is either simple (comprising the item's partition key) or composite (comprising the item's partition key and sort key). Your table's primary key is composite.

In DynamoDB, if a table has both a partition key and a sort key, any operation (like DeleteItem) must provide values for both keys to uniquely identify the item.
so this is how your code should look like:
public static DeleteItemResponse deleteDynamoDBItem(String partitionKey, String partitionKeyValue, String sortKey, int sortKeyValue) {

    Map<String, AttributeValue> keyToGet = new HashMap<>();

    keyToGet.put(partitionKey, AttributeValue.builder()
            .s(partitionKeyValue) // Partition key is a String
            .build());
    keyToGet.put(sortKey, AttributeValue.builder()
            .n(String.valueOf(sortKeyValue)) // Sort key is a Number, so convert int to String
            .build());

    DeleteItemRequest deleteReq = DeleteItemRequest.builder()
            .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .key(keyToGet)
            .build();

    try {
        return DYNAMO_DB.deleteItem(deleteReq);
    } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}

and then you can easily call:
DeleteItemResponse response = DataService.deleteDynamoDBItem("userid", "abc", "age", 89);


Thanks I did try that but still I get the same error "The provided key element does not match the schema" in cloudwatch logs

Acutally the issue was for sort key I was using .s() instead of .n() and after this change it is working.Another question I had was how to delete all items just be providing partition key? I'm unable to find any example based on that.

You need to basically query all of them. so List the items with a specific partition key (then you'll have the partition key and sort key), afterwards you can batch delete them. but only 25 at a time.
